# "Bluetooth is not available on this device" but I used it before

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, bluetooth

I have a Windows 10 Pro PC. Works great. Wanted to hook my Joy-Con controllers again to use some emulators. Proceed to spend the next 2 hours trying to figure out why bluetooth will not "connect" only being left with this cryptic message left by the troubleshooter.

[image]

Stuff I've tried:

Restarting my PC, reinstalling Bluetooth drivers, restarting services

Some other images that could help are below.

No Bluetooth shown in the Device Manager at all
[image]

Attempting to add a new Bluetooth device
[image]

UPDATE:

I have ran Ubuntu on a Live CD to see if it was hardware or an OS problem. It did not detect my machine had Bluetooth. Does this mean something responsible for Bluetooth got unplugged? The only thing I could think of would be the little Intel Wi-Fi bands on the back of my PC, but those are securely plugged in and don't really have problems.

Comment: Rollback to a previous version using a restore point.

Comment: @Valat,I agree, my pc used to have the same problem...in my previous window 10 i updated the driver but bluetooth kept appearing and disappearing..But in my new windows 10, its stable

Comment: What’s your hardware? You say you have Intel Wi-Fi, which model exactly? How is it installed in the PC? M.2 card, PCIe card, …? Did you check yet whether any connectors may have become loose?

Comment: It's the AC Dual-Band 3168, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

One of the cables connected to the Wi-Fi card came unplugged, somehow. Plugged it back in, and Bluetooth is now working again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a label printer that stopped working because of a Windows Update. (The update a few months ago broke ALL Dymo printers unless you were using an old version of their software).  I wonder if the same thing happened to you, did your computer update recently?  Also, if it's a laptop, some of them have the ability to turn off BlueTooth and Wifi, similar to Airplane mode.

Answer (score -1):

Try updating the driver I’ve had this issue before and was able to fix it manually. I found a great website explaining how to update any and all drivers (including Bluetooth) let me know if this helps
https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/bluetooth-not-showing-in-device-manager-fixed/

Comment: > Stuff I've tried: reinstalling Bluetooth drivers

Comment: Okay 2 questions the first is what make and model is your computer and the second is does it have a wireless killswitch

Comment: The model is in the comments in the initial post, and what do you mean by a wireless killswitch?